# Nativescript + Android: Socket connection timed out

Tags: android, nativescript

I created a basic nativescript project using Hello World template.

```
tns create
```

When I try to run it on a device

```
tns run android
```

I am getting error: Socket connection timed out..

[image]

When I try to run on device from Sidekick, I am getting similar error:

> Error detected during LiveSync on emulator-5554 for D:\TestZone\Android\HelloWorldApp. Error: Socket connection timed out.

I have Android Studio installed, also I followed Nativescript setup guidence (https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/start/ns-setup-win).

When i run

```
tns doctor
```

there are no issues detected. I wonder what I am missing?

Comment: Did you try starting the emulator manually and then `tns run`?

Comment: Yes, I am starting emulator from Android Studio

Comment: If you hit `adb devices` & `tns devices` do you see the device?

Comment: Yes, I can see the device with both commands

Comment: Your application id in package.json and manifest are same?

Comment: Yes, i changed them manually to be the same... but I am still getting the error

Comment: I've removed Nexus 5 and added Pixel 3 instead... now emulator works. Thanks for the help.